# Cypress: How to write tests to handle slow backend services?

Tags: timeout, cypress, react-component

I am working on a Cypress test set expected for validating a React website from **STAGE** to **DEMO** to **PROD**. The React components are generated using Redux pulling data from multiple backend services.

For **DEMO** and **PROD**, performance from backend services is optimal, and loading the React components is minimal delay, 5 seconds max.

For **STAGE**, the loading of the React components has a truly significant delay, 30+ seconds to rediculous 120 seconds. Yet, the components eventually render.

Cypress tests work 100% fine with both **DEMO** and **PROD**. I set the default `timeout` in `cypress.json` to **60000 ms**, but this long of default timeout is not necessary for these deployment environments.

However, the same Cypress tests ran against the same React site on **STAGE** deployment, `cy.visit()` and `cy.get()` fails often, even if I set timeout to **120000 ms**. Even if I add retry to 3, it fails.

So, how should best address Cypress waiting for React component loading because of unpredictable response from backend services?

Thank you, much appreciate the assistance

Comment: A long default timeout for Stage would not delay tests in Prod - commands will move on as soon as their expectations are met. It sounds like something else is going on in Stage, if 2 minutes is too short a time - connection dropped?

Comment: @MarionMorrison Thank you for your response. PROD and DEMO deployments, redux rendering of react components are fine because backend services are responsive. It is the backend services of STAGE deployment that is slow but the website's React components do render and its actions do work. However, the same Cypress tests that pass on DEMO and PROD only fail  on STAGE, even with the long timeout, when calling cy.get('component').

Comment: @MarionMorrison Addendum, STAGE backend services are not having connection drops, but sometimes can be painfully slow, not always. I do not have control in improving the response speed of the STAGE's backend services, and they are not the same backend services used by DEMO and PROD.

Comment: @JeffTanner If your tests are failing on `cy.visit()` then you have to provide `pageLoadTimeout` in your cypress.json. And secondly, if you write a recursive function and check for the presence of the element and reloading the page till its found, would it solve your purpose?

Comment: @AlapanDas Thank you for your response. Following up to your comment "...write a recursive function and check for the presence of the element and reloading the page till its found...". Do you have a reference for performing this action? I was not aware that you could do this in Cypress. Both `cy.get()` and `cy.visit()` fail the test, but I am not aware of recursive check.

Comment: @JeffTanner, thanks for the extra notes. Logic says if Stage is just slower than the other environs, then you should be able to find a timeout that works for Stage. Something does not sound right about the narrative. What is the page load time when accessing Stage in the browser (not Cypress test)?

Comment: @MarionMorrison I agree something is not right. I am now working with `cy.contains` to wait for component to appear. Will provide update later today.

Comment: `cy.contains()` would be my suggestion if Stage page load in browser is better then 2 mins - `cy.get(selector).contains(content)` does not wait for content from the server. You would get a quicker answer if you post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MarionMorrison @AlapanDas, thank you for your responses

I did resolve the problem within another posting which I did not realize at the time were the same question:

[Cypress: Wait for unpredictable component to render from an exclusive set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64421563/cypress-wait-for-unpredictable-component-to-render-from-an-exclusive-set)

I have been using both [Cypress `contains`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html) and [npm cypress-wait-until](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until) for resolve waiting for slow backend service responses.