# Cypress: Wait for unpredictable component to render from an exclusive set?

Tags: cypress

For thorough testing, my **service (UI+Backend)** migrates through multiple deployment environments: ex DEV, STAGE, DEMO, and PROD. As this service migrates these test environments, its UI waits for **asynchronous updates** from its Backend, which as a test stressor it can be **unpredictably** slow; thereby, speeding it up is not an option nor is mocking the response.

UI test involves waiting for an **asynchronous update** response to determine which React components will exclusively be presented. These React components will be **section/div** with **unpredictable content/text**, so [`Cypress contains`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Syntax) is not an option.

The typical solution for handling slow **asynchronous updates** is using **fixed delays** with [`Cypress wait`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html): a bunch of milliseconds, tenths of a second, or even seconds. However, the longer are fixed delays leads your test to be **more brittle**.

Here is an example of my brittle Cypress test code:

```
cy.get('div.main')
  .then( ($divMain) => {
    cy.wait(5000) // wait 5 seconds

    const boolStateA = $divMain.find('section.A').length > 0;
    const boolStateB = $divMain.find('section.B').length > 0;

    if (boolStateA( {
      // Do ...
    } else if ( boolStateB ) {
      // Do something else ...
    }
  })
```

However.. after waiting for 5 seconds, it is not absolutely certain, that either one of the components actually rendered. If neither or both rendered, then that is an unexpected state.

So how can I wait for either of these components to render using neither `cy.wait()` nor `cy.contains`?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@GrayDwarf: Thank you for your response

I did use [Cypress `contains`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Syntax)

```js
cy.get('div[data-cy="sales_listing_section"]')
    .contains(
        'h1.header-title[data-cy="sale_items_header"]',
        'Items for Sale',
        {timeout: 10000}
    )
    .then(() => {
```

As well as module [npm cypress-wait-until](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until)

```js
cy.get('div.main-content')
    .then(($sectionBody) => {

        // @ts-ignore
        cy.waitUntil(() => {
            return ($sectionBody.find('div[data-cy="sales_listing_section"]').length > 0)
        }, {
            errorMsg: `ERROR: Sales section has not loaded.`,
            timeout: 10000, // waits up to 10000 ms, default to 5000
            interval: 500, // performs the check every 500 ms, default to 200
            verbose: true,
            customCheckMessage: `CHECK: If Sales section has loaded`
        })
            .then(() => {
                cy.log('Sales section', 'Loading finished');
            })
    })
```

Comment: waitUntil part is good hint, I was facing issue with react rerender, and it solves the issue.

Comment: In this code block waitUntil has minimal effect. It's pretty much equivalent to `cy.get('div.main-content').find('div[data-cy="sales_listing_section"]', {timeout: 10_000})`.

Answer (score 8):

To wait for either `<section class="A">` or `<section class="B">`, use a [muliple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Cypress will wait for the first one to show up, and you can just add a timeout (since 5s is a bit above the default timeout).

```js
cy.get('div.main')
  .find('section.A, section.B', {timeout:5_000})
  .then($section => {

    if ($section.hasClass("A") {          
      
    } 

    if ($section.hasClass("B") {          
      
    }
  })
```

A further example: [Cypress assert A or B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71315937/cypress-assert-a-or-b)

Answer (score 5):

The recommendation from cypress is to make your testing deterministic. Meaning, figure out how to ensure your product is always in a known state when your tests run. This is typically done with mocks, routes or messaging the backend to provide (or perhaps get) a pre-determined state.

An inline timeout could be a bit better than cy.wait() but that doesn't resolve your unknown state problem.

```js
cy.get('.mobile-nav', { timeout: 10000 })
  .should('be.visible')
  .and('contain', 'Home')
```

Alternatively, you could update your app to include a hidden done state that your tests wait for.

Example:

```html
<div data-cy="SectionLoaded">SectionA</div>
```

In this manner, the test only needs to wait for one thing and it's always going to be there. Your test can have a condition that gets the .text() of this element and then acts on it. That might look something like this provided you wanted to click on one of them.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=SectionLoaded]', { timeout: 10000 }).then(($loadedSection) => {
cy.get(`[data-cy=${$loadedSection.text()}]`).click()
```

More on this from cypress.io including additional best practices and workarounds:

- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Element-existence
- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Dynamic-text
- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html#Increase-time-to-retry

Comment: Thank you for response. As stated, either `<section.A>` or `<section.B>` components will be generated exclusively (neither will appear as the same time), and neither will contain text, so I cannot use `.text()`. Using `cy.get('section.A')` will fail if it never appears but `cy.get('section.B')` will succeed, and vice versa. So, I could use `cy.find('section.A')` and `cy.find('section.B')` but choosing `cy.wait(...)` timeout will make the test fragile. I will work with pre-determined state, but it is the time waiting for expected pre-determined state is the issue.

Comment: Waiting for a predetermined state shouldn't be an issue so I'm confused by your closing remark. cypress automatically handles waiting for certain commands like get() and provides control over how long it retries for. Seems like your issue is with not knowing what state the page will be be in when it's done loading. Will it have section.A or section.B or neither? My suggestion for using .text() was for the case where you update your web application to inject a bit of into about what sections were added to the page.

Example workflow:
<html>
... no sections added
</html>

<html>

Comment: Correction: "... inject a bit of info". Was also trying to provide a visual example in my comment that got posted by accident. Can't format it either so it will be inline. By injecting this element, your test will deterministically wait for SectionsAdded which has information about which section was added. 

<html>
<section.A> added</section.A>
<div data-cy="SectionsAdded">A</a>
</html>

Comment: Page will present `section.A` **XOR** `section.B`, **exclusive or**: one or the other but never both and never neither. Correct, I will not know the state the page will be until it's done loading. Thank you.