# Cypress assert A or B

Tags: cypress

I want to make an assertion in Cypress as follows:

```js
cy.get(a).should('be.visible').or(()=>{
    cy.get(b).should('be.visible');
});
```

In other words, I want to check if condition A or condition B is true. How to do this in Cypress?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to use the [jQuery multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/). It will require moving the `visible` assertion inside the the selector using [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

```js
cy.get('a:visible, b:visible')
```

Be aware you sacrifice some of Cypress' built-in retry (as with all conditional testing).

For example, if `b:visible` now but `a:visible` in 1 second, it will give you `b`. Whereas `cy.get(a).should('be.visible')` will wait the second and return `a`.

Depending on details of the scenario, there are other ways.

Comment: You have no idea how that multiple selector thing made my life easier. Thanks man.